# Voice command to output "\ref{}" in Dragon Dictate 4

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

I want to define a voice command that outputs "\ref{}" in [Dragon Dictate 4](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/dragon-dictate/index.htm). When I define the following voice command:

[image]

the output is:

```
[blank line]
ef{}
```

Basically `\r` is interpreted as a [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). How can I escape this? I would prefer a solution that works as the text macro (it should be easy to do it in Automator as a last resort otherwise).

I tried writing `\\ref{}` as [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) but it didn't work, I get the following:

```
\
[blank line]
ef{}
```